# dynamically increase tableview cells based on entered value in textfield which is in cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm new to swift. I have an UITableView with one custom UITableViewCell. It has one UITextfield. By default numberOfRows is 1.

When I enter an integer value(x) in that textfield and hit enter, the tableview should append x number of tableviewcells and every cell should have a textfield.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : TableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.textField?.text = "Created"
    cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldShouldReturn()), forControlEvents: <#T##UIControlEvents#>)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking for. What do you mean by "entered n values" and "increase n times"?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want set a IBAction when the user finishes editing to check if the value inserted is a valid number, if it is increment the number of records on your datasource and call tableView.reloadData() to refresh the table.

On your cellForRowAtIndexPath you can have a verification on the row in case you want cells different from the first one like so

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textField?.text = "Created"
        cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
        UITextField().addTarget(self, action: #selector(customMethod), for: .editingDidEnd)
    } else {
        cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("otherCell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Created programatically"
    }

    return cell
}
```